# How to set custom icon height for Tab bar icon while using React Native Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there a way to set custom icon height and width for tab bar buttons?

Thanks!

```
search() {
return {
  name: 'search',
  screen: 'entry.Entry',
  title: "Entry",
  titleImage: true,
  navigatorButtons: {
    leftButtons: [{
      id: 'back-button',
      component: 'entry.BackButton'
    }]
  },
  icon: require("./navigationAssets/searchIconInactive.png"),
  selectedIcon: require(./navigationAssets/searchIconActive.png")
};
```

}

Comment: please add more details to your question

Answer (score 0):

you following code

```
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    // Note: By default the icon is only shown on iOS. Search the showIcon option below.
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
      />
    ),
  };
```

refer this link. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab

i hope it's help for you